# .htaccess redirect all subcategories if page is in /shop/ subcategory

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, directory

**Question:**

How can I use .htaccess to 301 redirect all subdirectories (and subdirectories of subdirectories) in the subdirectory /shop/ to the root *and* keep all parameters?

**Situation:**

I have a webshop with the following structure:

```
    http://www.domain.com/shop/category1/category2/category3/product1.html?utm=code&source=web
    http://www.domain.com/shop/category1/product2
    http://www.domain.com/shop/category1/category6/product3
```

We're working on a new shop with a different structure. What I'd like to have is a 301 redirect to the root of the domain, so the old url is as follows:

```
    http://www.domain.com/shop/category1/category2/category3/product1.html?utm=code&source=web
```

This URL will redirect to:

```
    http://www.domain.com/product1?utm=code&source=web
```

I need to remove /shop/, other subcategories but keep the parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /shop/cat1/cat2/cat3/product\.html\?utm=([^\&]+)&source=([^&\s]+) [NC] 
RewriteRule ^ /product?utm=%1&source=%1 [NC,R,L]
```